# Why must you be careful when using Bash's built in command history function to re-run previous commands that contain variables?

Tags: bash, command-history, function, variable

I know `!!` re-runs commands but what exactly would occur if I re-ran a command that had a variable in the command?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange network :). Please take the time to qualify your question further. As it stands, it's unclear what the problem is. Maybe give an example of such a command that you think would be problematic to rerun using `!!`. Please also explain what led you to think that this would be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's try it:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo $foo
bar
$ foo=qux
$ !-2
echo $foo
qux
$ history
...
  219  foo=bar
  220  echo $foo
  221  foo=qux
  222  echo $foo
  223  history
```

So it appears that the command is added to history *before* variable expansion occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some trial and error could prove useful and provide a result for you very quickly. Before you ask a question it is good to try these things out yourself. As a result you can ask informed and detailed questions :)

As it seem you are quite new to this perhaps the following would be of benefit to you?

```
$ history -c
$ FOOD="Bananas"
$ echo $FOOD
Bananas
$ history
  137  FOOD="Bananas"
  138  echo $FOOD
  139  history
$ !138
echo $FOOD
Bananas
```

As you can see, the `history` command worked as expected. By executing 138 we executed the exact same command that we did the first time we ran it.

Pro Tip: use the `man` command to read more about a command that you are curious about. Ex:

```
man history
```

and type <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit when you are done.

Cheers!